# PHP - Splitting an array, based on inputtype (key)

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form that sends a big amount of mixed data (radio input, textfields and checkboxes), in an associative array. To store the data, i would like to split the data into smaller arrays, based on the inputtypes. The var_dump is showed below.

[ATM i get this when i var_dump the array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMe1m.png)

So how do i make new arrays, containing the r** keys, the textbox** keys and the checkbox** keys?

```
$arr = array( "r11"=> "2",
    "tekstbox11"=> "A",
    "udskift11"=> "on",
    "r12"=> "2",
    "tekstbox12"=> "B",
    "udskift12"=> "on",
    "r13"=> "2",
    "tekstbox13"=> "C",
    "udskift13"=> "on",
    "r14"=> "0",
    "tekstbox14"=> "",
    "r15"=> "1",
    "tekstbox15"=> "",
    "r16"=> "0",
    "tekstbox16"=> "",
    "r17"=> "1",
    "tekstbox17"=> "",
    "r18"=> "0",
    "tekstbox18"=> "",
    "r19"=> "1",
    "tekstbox19"=> "",
    "r110"=> "0",
    "tekstbox110"=> "",
    "r111"=> "1",
    "textbox111"=> "",
    "r112"=> "0",
    "textbox112"=> "",
    "r113"=> "1",
    "textbox113"=> "",
    "r114"=> "0",
    "textbox114"=> "",
    "r115"=> "1",
    "textbox115"=> "",
    "r116"=> "0",
    "textbox116"=> "",
    "r117"=> "1",
    "textbox117"=> "",
    "r118"=> "0",
    "textbox118"=> "",
    "r119"=> "1",
    "textbox119"=> "",
    "r120"=> "0",
    "textbox120"=> "",
    "r21"=> "2",
    "tekstbox21"=> "a",
    "r22"=> "2",
    "tekstbox22"=> "b",
    "r23"=> "2",
    "tekstbox23"=> "c",
    "r24"=> "0",
    "tekstbox24"=> "",
    "r25"=> "1",
    "textbox25"=> "",
    "r26"=> "0",
    "textbox26"=> "",
    "r27"=> "1",
    "textbox27"=> "",
    "r28"=> "0",
    "textbox28"=> "",
    "r31"=> "2",
    "tekstbox31"=> "1m",
    "udskift31"=> "on",
    "r32"=> "2",
    "tekstbox32"=> "2m",
    "udskift32"=> "on",
    "r33"=> "2",
    "tekstbox33"=> "3m",
    "udskift33"=> "on",
    "r34"=> "2",
    "tekstbox34"=> "4m",
    "udskift34"=> "on",
    "r35"=> "0",
    "tekstbox35"=> "",
    "r36"=> "0",
    "tekstbox36"=> "",
    "r37"=> "0",
    "tekstbox37"=> "",
    "r38"=> "0",
    "tekstbox38"=> "",
    "r39"=> "0",
    "tekstbox39"=> "",
    "r310"=> "0",
    "tekstbox310"=> "",
    "r311"=> "0",
    "tekstbox311"=> "",
    "r312"=> "0",
    "tekstbox312"=> "",
    "r313"=> "0",
    "tekstbox313"=> "",
    "r314"=> "1",
    "textbox314"=> "",
    "r315"=> "1",
    "textbox315"=> "",
    "r316"=> "1",
    "textbox316"=> "",
    "r317"=> "1",
    "textbox317"=> "",
    "r318"=> "1",
    "textbox318"=> "",
    "r319"=> "1",
    "textbox319"=> "",
    "r320"=> "1",
    "textbox320"=> "",
    "r321"=> "1",
    "textbox321"=> "",
    "r322"=> "1",
    "textbox322"=> "",
    "r323"=> "1",
    "textbox323"=> "",
    "r324"=> "1",
    "textbox324"=> "",
    "r325"=> "1",
    "textbox325"=> "",
    "r326"=> "2",
    "textbox326"=> "SLUT MED",
    "udskift326"=> "on"
);
```

Comment: Please post your array as code and not an image. `echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, 1) . '</pre>'` will format it nicely. I might be able to help once you do this. But it takes too long to type your array manually.

Comment: Please post your array as code and not an image.

Comment: Sorry about that. What about now?

Comment: Did you just want the keys, or also the values, in an associative array? I have an answer ready, but just want to make sure its correct.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher in the end i only need the values, to further prossesing and store them in the Database. - Eriks answer does what i need, so i'll just go with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the array and split the keys into alpha and numeric parts, then use those parts as keys in the result array.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    preg_match('/(\D+)(\d+)/', $key, $parts);
    $result[$parts[1]][$parts[2]] = $value;
    //    alpha^    numeric^
}
```

The result will be like

```
$result = [
    'r' => ['11' => 2, '12'=> 2, ...],
    'tekstbox' => ['11' => 'A', '12'=> 'B', ...],
    'udskift' => ['11' => 'on' => '12' => 'on' ...]
];
```

But you know, you can also achieve the same result if you just rename your form inputs like:

```
 <input type="text" name="r[11]">
```

Comment: Thanks for the input with the html. I wasn't aware of that, and it completely solves my problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to inspect the key.

```
<?php 
$inputArray = [
    'text1' => 'text1',
    'text2' => 'text2',
    'checkbox1' => 'checkbox1',
    'checkbox2' => 'checkbox2',
    'radio1' => 'radio1',
    'radio2' => 'radio2'
];

$radioArray = array_filter($inputArray, function($key) {
    return false !== strpos($key, 'radio');
});
$textArray = array_filter($inputArray, function($key) {
    return false !== strpos($key, 'text');
});
$checkboxArray = array_filter($inputArray, function($key) {
    return false !== strpos($key, 'checkbox');
});
```